# Adding Multiple Deadlines to One Task

Tags: ms-project-2010, deadline

I am a new user to Microsoft Project. My company are currently using Project 2010 so I am having to use this version.

I noticed that I can add deadlines to individual tasks, which is really useful for me. When I do this I get a Green arrow at the end of each task. I now want to add a second arrow of a different colour to the same task. The reason for this is that within my company each task must be peer checked, so I want to add a deadline when a task must be submitted for peer checking and then a final deadline (the green arrow) when the task must be fully signed off.

I know I could just use multiple tasks to show this but I want it to be shown on one bar of my schedule.

I hope that makes sense.

Thanks,
Tom

Comment: I can't answer the original question as I don't think this is possible (others may know otherwise), however I would always show this as two separate tasks - one being the task itself, and the other being the peer check. I would consider putting all of the peer check tasks into one area of the plan, so that you could see how the peer checking is progressing, as an alternative to placing these beside the original tasks.

Comment: Thinking more about this, I don't think it is logical for a single task to have multiple deadlines. Either the task is complete or it isn't. During the period between completing the work and having it signed off, is the task complete or not? If yes, then the sign-off is a separate task. If no, then the sign-off is part of the task.

Comment: @Iain9688 I understand your point regarding a task having multiple deadlines, I suppose for Microsoft projects it does make more sense to have two separate tasks with a deadline for each. Really I was attempting to minimize the number of tasks on my schedule which is already fairly large and so an additional icon showing where peer checking begins would have been useful.